# URL Redirect to different web servers based on input URL

Tags: .net, http, ssl, redirect, iis

I have below requirement to implement.

Example 1
User Input URL in browser --> https://ssltest.com/demo1 --> This will Open to http://demo1.com

Example 2
User Input URL in browser --> https://ssltest.com/demo2 --> This will Open to http://demo2.com

This kind of implementation is required as we have limited number of SSL certificates.

I have tried few approaches using IIS URL rewrite feature but no success yet.

Please help with this implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The domain https://ssltest.com/ is for sale, and yet you're using it for some kind of redirection?

Comment: @stuartd Yes Domain SSL test will be having SSL certificate other sites like http://demo1.com are internal URL to different web applications and basis of /demo1 & /demo2 redirection is required to applications hosted on different servers.

Comment: Rewriting a domain to another domain requires the use of redirection. What are your rewrite rules?